# Specifying port number on client side

Tags: c, sockets, unix

How can I make sure that my client uses a particular port to connect to server in a typical server client program. Like in server side we are using a port number in bind system call and then listen on that particular port, is there any way we can specify the port number on the client side and uses the same port to connect to server. Server = 3456 , 
    Client = 7834 ( I want to specify this port number so that client uses 7834 for connection). I am trying in C and Unix platform.

Comment: In order to successfully make a connection, the client must connect to the port number on which the server is actually listening. It's unclear what you are asking here, because using different port numbers won't work.

Comment: @GregHewgill I believe he's asking about the client's source port. Which is not configurable, as far as I understand. You simply get "the next one" available.

Comment: Oh, well I think you can bind the client to a particular source port, but there's hardly ever a reason why you would want to do that.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Yes you are right, I am asking about client source port only. Sorry for my bad English. Gerg Hewgill told that we can bind it.. which system call we will use to do so? Is it the same bind system call?

Answer (score 7):

You do this on the client side exactly as you do it on the server side - using `bind()`.  It's just that the client calls `connect()` after `bind()` instead of calling `listen()`.

Note that you will only be able to run one instance of the client on each machine if you do this, and your server might see a different client port anyway if there are network middleboxes using address translation between the client and server.

Answer (score 4):

The client program can set sockaddr...sin_port and then call bind() before connecting and it will get, subject to availability, the requested outgoing port.

The server can verify this port is set manually by calling getpeername() and checking it.

As others have said though, you dont really need to set the outgoing port usually, unless you have something weird going on, or specific requirements.

Comment: Some network protocols require specific/predictable client source ports.  And sometimes firewalls/routers are locked down to allow only certain client source ports. So there are some valid reasons to bind a client source port before connecting.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There is no valid reason I am aware of for a firewall configuration to lock down an outgoing port number. I used to hear of netadmins doing this 'for security reasons' in the 1990s but I thought the practice had died out after people like me started asking '*what* security reasons?'

Answer (score 1):

It's similar with server side, usually we do

```
local_addr.sin_port   = htons(INADDR_ANY);
```

because port number is not important. Instead, you can use

```
local_addr.sin_port   = htons(src_port);  /Use the src_port as you like
```

And then call `bind`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution that runs in debian linux on the ts-7500 sbc.  it should port pretty easy.   This solution also looks up the ip address of the client machine automatically.

```
     /*dl_senderprog.c - debian linux send to server a client, datagram*/

 /***********************************************************************


 140203  lets see if we can bind to a port

 ts7500:/var/www/jon/uvir_sensor_lab/source/socket#
 ts7500:/var/www/jon/uvir_sensor_lab/source/socket# vi senderprog_bind.c
 ts7500:/var/www/jon/uvir_sensor_lab/source/socket# gcc -g senderprog_bind.c -o senderprog_bind
 ts7500:/var/www/jon/uvir_sensor_lab/source/socket# ./senderprog_bind
 Sender:Client-Usage: ./senderprog_bind <hostname> <message>
 ts7500:/var/www/jon/uvir_sensor_lab/source/socket#
 ts7500:/var/www/jon/uvir_sensor_lab/source/socket#
 ts7500:/var/www/jon/uvir_sensor_lab/source/socket# ./senderprog_bind 10.0.1.26 "dot,33,22"
 MY IP address:10.0.1.242: on port: 1043
 Sender: Client-gethostname() is OK...
 Sender: Client-socket() sockfd is OK...
 Sender: Using port: 14950
 Sender: Client-sendto() is OK...
 Sender: sent 9 bytes to 10.0.1.26
 Sender: Client-sockfd successfully closed!
 ts7500:/var/www/jon/uvir_sensor_lab/source/socket#
 ts7500:/var/www/jon/uvir_sensor_lab/source/socket#
 ts7500:/var/www/jon/uvir_sensor_lab/source/socket# # it worked!!!!!
 ts7500:/var/www/jon/uvir_sensor_lab/source/socket#



 ***********************************************************************/




 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
 #include <netdb.h>

 #include <sys/ioctl.h>
 #include <net/if.h>





 /* the port users will be connecting to 14950 is the port on the windows machine
    that I have the server running on */
 #define TOPORT 14950
 #define MYPORT 1043

 void my_ip( char *myniccard, char *myipaddr) {
      int fd;
      struct ifreq ifr;

      myipaddr[0]=0;

      fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

      /* I want to get an IPv4 IP address */
      ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;

      /* I want IP address attached to "eth0" */
      //strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ-1);
      strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, myniccard, IFNAMSIZ-1);

      ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);

      close(fd);

      /* display result */
      sprintf(myipaddr,"%s"
        , inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr));
      printf("MY IP address:%s: on port: %d\n", myipaddr, MYPORT);

      }   // my_ip


 int main(int argc, char *argv[ ])
 {
 int sockfd;
 /* connectors address information */
 struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
 struct sockaddr_in localaddr;
 char myipaddressm[22];   //buffer for ip address
 char *myniccardm ="eth0";   // check with ipconfig for correct ethernet port

 struct hostent *he;
 int numbytes;

 if (argc != 3) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Sender:Client-Usage: %s <hostname> <message>\n", argv[0]);
      exit(1);
      }

 my_ip(myniccardm, myipaddressm);


 /* get the host info */
 if ((he = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL) {
      perror("Sender: Client-gethostbyname() error lol!");
      exit(1);
      }
  else
      printf("Sender: Client-gethostname() is OK...\n");

 if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
       perror("Sender: Client-socket() error lol!");
       exit(1);
       }
   else
       printf("Sender: Client-socket() sockfd is OK...\n");


 // Bind to a specific network interface
 // (this is unusual, as you normally do not want a specific
 //  port for the client, but we have a specific server in
 //  this case that will not accept connects unless its on
 //  a specific port )
 localaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 localaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(myipaddressm);
 localaddr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);  // Any local port will do
 bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&localaddr, sizeof(localaddr));



 /* host byte order */
 their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 /* short, network byte order */
 printf("Sender: Using port: %d\n",TOPORT);
 their_addr.sin_port = htons(TOPORT);
 their_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
 /* zero the rest of the struct */
 memset(&(their_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

 if((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, argv[2],
                       strlen(argv[2]),
                       0,
                       (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr,
                       sizeof(struct sockaddr))) == -1) {
       perror("Sender: Client-sendto() error lol!");
       exit(1);
       }
   else
       printf("Sender: Client-sendto() is OK...\n");

 printf("Sender: sent %d bytes to %s\n", numbytes, inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr));

 if (close(sockfd) != 0)
       printf("Sender: Client-sockfd closing is failed!\n");
   else
       printf("Sender: Client-sockfd successfully closed!\n");
 return 0;

 }//main


 /*******************************************EOF***********************/
```